# Which French acronyms are most likely to be needed?

Tags: abréviations

Here is a link to About.com's collection of common French acronyms. There's about 100-150 of them, and probably someone from France will recognize them all in a heartbeat.

http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-acronyms.htm

I'm trying to get as firm a grasp on French language and culture as possible, and I'd like to be familiar with common acronyms, but there's no way I'm going to remember all of those without spending an extended amount of time in France. I would like to commit to memory the top 25-30 that are *most important* and *most likely to be needed* in conversation/getting around.

Can a native French person take a look at the list and pick out the ones which you know to be most crucial? I suppose this is somewhat subjective, but I feel it's a legitimate question.

Comment: Here's a north-american [complement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=153&niveau=).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En voilà une trentaine, extraits de cette liste, qui apparaissent très fréquemment :

> BD – Bande dessinée
>   càd – C'est-à-dire
>   Cie – Compagnie
>   CRS – Compagnie républicaine de sécurité
>   DOM-TOM – Départements d'outre-mer et Territoires d'outre-mer
>   EDF / GDF – Électricité de France / Gaz de France
>   Go / Mo / Ko – Giga/Méga/Kilo octet
>   HLM – Habitation à loyer modéré
>   HS – Hors service
>   HT / TTC / TVA – Hors taxe / Toutes taxes comprises / Taxe sur la valeur ajoutée
>   NdT / NDLR – Note du traducteur / de la rédaction
>   OGM – Organisme génétiquement modifié
>   OVNI – Objet volant non identifié (souvent employé au figuré)
>   PDG – Président Directeur Général
>   RDV – Rendez-vous
>   RMI / SMIC – Revenu minimum d'insertion / Salaire minimum interprofessionnel de croissance
>   SAMU – Secours d'aide médicale d'urgence
>   SDF – Sans domicile fixe
>   SNCF – Société nationale des chemins de fer français
>   SVP – S'il-vous-plaît
>   TGV – Train à grande vitesse
>   UE – Union européenne
>   QG – Quartier général

Comment: Je suggère de rajouter ONG et TVA.

Comment: ERDF et GRDF (ce sont eux qui envoient les factures !)

Comment: J'aurais gardé AOC.

Comment: RMI is now RSA: revenu de solidarité active

Comment: Just coming back and studying this 4 years later :) . . . The terms kilo/mega/gigabyte are not used in France? I have never once encountered this piece of information before.

Comment: @Aerovistae: If you use French on your computer or look at labels, bytes will appear as octets (and people normally use octets in spoken language). Bits are bits though.

Answer (score 1):

[NIP](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num%C3%A9ro_d%27identification_personnel) is the equivalent of PIN. It's bound to be something you end up using a lot!  Oops!  Just looked at the question and see you're asking for a "native French person", that's not me.  Just a visitor.

Comment: Visitors often see things that natives miss/take for granted.  The NIP/PIN distinction is indeed a very good thing to know; not only to facilitate credit/debit card transactions, but also to avoid confusion when family/friends in France ask you to send them some (lapel) [PIN’S!](http://www.pins-collection.com/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

É.U. et É.-U. ne sont pas usités : on parle d'US ou des USA. D'autant plus que l'accent sur les majuscules est très difficile à taper au clavier :
cela devient E.U. qui renvoie à l'Union Européenne.

LlH -> L60,l40,H75 dans un catalogue de meuble par exemple.

C'est fini pour les ASSEDIC et l'ANPE qui sont regroupés maintenant dans Pôle Emploi

Le RMI est transformé en [RSA](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/N19775.xhtml).

le - dans les abréviations (W.-C.) est typographiquement correct, mais souvent omis au quotidien.

Il serait intéressant de connaître quels sont vos centres d’intérêt pour mettre en exergue les acronymes que vous allez le plus souvent rencontrer.

Answer (score 0):

Voici une liste un peu plus complète que celle ci-dessus : http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-acronyms.htm

Comment: This link was given in the question :-)

Comment: oops sorry (i tried to answer to the duplicate question, which didn't has this link) ! Then i guess he got the main acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

*VTT* (*vélo tout-terrain*): mountain biking

*CTT* (*course tout-terrain*): trail running

Answer (score 0):

Dans le genre liste pas très sélective et très administrative, vous avez celle du *Code de rédaction interinstitutionnel de l'Union européenne* — édition française —, dans l'[annexe A4](http://publications.europa.eu/code/fr/fr-5000400.htm).

Je précise à toutes fins utiles que lui et ses homologues européens sont gratuits (port compris) pour tout habitant de l'UE, et qu'il en existe un par langue. Cela fait une bonne base de départ pour les questions de typographie ou d'usage, pour un prix nul.

J'en profite aussi pour dire qu'à mon sens, l'usage de sigles est le signe d'un accaparement de la langue par l'administration et les entreprises (noms propres, institutions, normes) avec le consentement parfois réjoui des lecteurs, qui transpose cette siglite partout dans la langue, en particulier sur Internet (RTFM) ou dans l'inénarrable “monde de l'entreprise” (ASAP).

Si vous apprenez le français et que vous cherchez un peu d'élégance, laissez tout cela aux énarques et aux informaticiens. ÀMHA… LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my response will not be irrelevant with question above. There are also some abbreviations used to know on chats (on Facebook etc.) like :

mdr : mort de rire
ptdr : pété de rire

Also, an acronym that you can see so many time is RATP.

RATP : Régie Autonome des Transports Parisiens